# When input string is the same as key string, do something

Tags: python, dictionary, input

I'm using Python 3 trying to print specific statements if the user input matches a dictionary key. I'm getting the error "dict' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" which is fair enough because a string is not an integer.

Below is a sample from my dictionary and wat I want the code to do is print the dictionary entry for the dog "Mouch" i.e. user input is "Mouch" so the cell returns "Most cleverist".

```py
doggies = {"Mouch":"most cleverist"}
print("Who\'s a clever girl?")
doggo = input()
for doggos in range(doggies):
    if doggo == "Mouch":
        print(doggies[Mouch])
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you already have a dictionary you can access the elements of that dictionary with their key. So you can simply write

```
doggies = {"Mouch":"most cleverist"}
print("Who\'s a clever girl?")
doggo = input()
if doggo in doggies:
    print(doggies[doggo])
```

That's kind of what dictionaries are made for

Comment: Well, no. If `doggo` is not one of the keys, that will cause an exception.

Comment: yeah sry keep switching between languages ^^; 
corrected it

Comment: Must be a language switch thing... There's no `has_key` method of Python dicts either ;)

Comment: okay i give up; that was my python2 brain (which had has_key) kicking in
really should go to sleep

Comment: Right... That's where I had once seen it! Enjoy the rest!

Answer (score 1):

This code will work:

```
doggies = {"Mouch":"most cleverist"}
print("Who\'s a clever girl?")
doggo = input()
for doggos in range(len(doggies)):
    if doggo == "Mouch":
        print(doggies['Mouch'])
```

But this code is a little strange:

- you have a dictionary with dogs
- you get user input
- you iterate over your dictionary and try to use user's input
  I'd suggest the following:

```
doggies = {"Mouch":"most cleverist"}
print("Who\'s a clever girl?")
doggo = input()

if doggo in doggies:
    print(doggies['Mouch'])
else:
    print('Unknown dog!')
```

Comment: Just write `if doggo in doggies`, you don't need the `.keys()`. In the same way, iterating on a dict iterates on its keys.